# AutoHotKey Recognizing itself as an input

Tags: autohotkey

I was making a real-time translator(not translate btw), that when I type a letter in my language, It automatically types an alphabet of corresponding sound.

```
r::
Send, t
return
```

You get the Idea, when I press 'r', It writes 't' instead.

Then the problem happened. As I added more and more letters, I stumbled upon this part:

```
f::
Send, r
return
```

When I type f, it types r.
Then it thought that I typed r (in fact, the program typed it), so it types t.

Ultimately, it types t when I press f. (which is not intended)

Is there a parameter or something that prevents it from recognizing its own key input as an input?

(also, I don't want to do this:

```
^r::
Send, t
return
```

Sure, This will solve the problem, but I have to hold the Ctrl key the whole time.)

Answer (score 1):

Good that you found the remapping syntax, it's very handy and is indeed what you want to use for this.
And for future reference, to solve the problem of `Send`ing triggering hotkeys, you want to use [`$`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar).

```
$2::MsgBox, % "You wont see me if you press 1"

1::SendInput, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, just had to do this

```
r::t
f::r
```

...